# Using subsubsection with section listing

Tags: sectioning, lists

I want to use the "style" of `\subsubsection`, but with the numbering of `\section` for my homework because I don't like how the document look with `enumerate`, the best/most beauty solution I could get was:

```
\subsubsection*{1. Question}

Answer

\subsubsection*{2. Question}

Answer
```

I want somehow to automate the process to don't need to manually put the number of the question, if there's another more efficient form to get the same or simmilar effect, I could use too.

Comment: There are several approaches to this. But this will depend on the document class and on your preamble, and on many other things. So please, try to post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). By the way, welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very minimal approach could be:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\textbf{\arabic{subsection}}.}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Question}
one
\subsection{Question}
two
\end{document}
```

[image]

But maybe the package [`titlesec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec?lang=en) can give more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is use something like:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{A question}

  The blank line is to force a new paragraph in this item.
\item \textbf{Another question}

  It is a \emph{bad} idea to fight \LaTeX.
  The source code of the document should describe the structure of the document,
  not use random constructs to get some appearance.
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: You have `\begin{enumerate}` but `\end{itemize}`. I guess you meant `\end{enumerate}`?